# What is AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL?

Tags: c, address-sanitizer

Address Sanitizer is reporting the following error:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==2385==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: BUS on unknown address 0x00080042a288 (pc 0x00080042a288 bp 0x7fffffffd2e0 sp 0x7fffffffd280 T0)
```

What does this mean generally?

Comment: The sanitizer have caught an error  - this is exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Some kind of undefined behavior, try compiling with debug symbols (`-g` for GCC/Clang) and maybe ASan will print out a stack trace. Look for the topmost line of code, the error is probably nearby.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean generally?

Your program jumped to a wild address, that AddressSanitizer knows nothing about.

The address actually doesn't look that wild, it's in the range where one could reasonably expect a 32-bit `i*86` Linux executable code to reside.

But you are running a 64-bit binary, and for such a binary that particular address doesn't make much sense.